# StackAuth.com user's id

Tags: support, users, associated

What ID should I pass to `stackauth.com/1.1/users/{id}/associated` url to get user's associations?

The description of the api call states:

> id – a set of up to 10 users' association ids, obtained from some
>   other API method. This is a vectorized parameter, multiple ids can be
>   sent in a single request if delimitted with a semi-colon string

What is this "some other API method"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get it from the users route, like I told you in your last question.  You can't use the Id from the stackexchange website. But in version 2.0 of the API you will highly likely be able to again.

Comment: v2.0 of the API is going to use account IDs instead of association GUIDs.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant to type :) somehow never made it from my brain to the keys :)